# HTK error : Requested data format is not supported

Tags: htk

I installed HTK tookit. It was happened when I terminated “hslab yes.sig” command line on win10 system.

The following the error :
ERROR [+6006]  StartAudi: Requested data format is not supported [ERR=2]
 FATAL ERROR - Terminating program hslab

Who can give a advice? Very thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not using hslab in windows environment. U can use SFS (speech filling system) and better recording apps, like cooledit or another 3rd party, or event internal win. sound recorder